# How can I prevent excel from automatically creating series in my vba generated chart?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to create a very basic scatterplot of an x column and a y column.

```
Dim c As Chart
Set c = sht.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With c

    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "GPC Plot"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B6", Range("B6").End(xlDown))
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("C6", Range("C6").End(xlDown))
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = sheetname
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Molecular Weight"
    .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 10000
    .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 10
    .Axes(xlCategory).ScaleType = xlLogarithmic
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 225
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0


End With
```

I just want the chart with the one data series, but Excel keeps generating a chart with 5 other series using random data from the sheet that I am creating the chart on. Is there a way I can prevent excel from automatically doing this?

Comment: I think your range is at fault here: .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B6", Range("B6").End(xlDown)), have you got another 5 rows below B6? if so then that's where your extra data is coming from...

Comment: I do actually (about 6,000 rows). Since posting I have actually changed it to .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B6", Cells(UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)). I still run into the same issue. It seems as though excel is "suggesting" data (like it does if you manually add a chart). Any idea on how I might fix this? I'm considering just manually doing a for loop at the end to delete any series after SeriesCollection(1) but I would like to find a solution that prevents it from happening in the first place if that's possible. thanks for your help

Comment: Well where is the actual data you would like to chart, why not reference that range as an absolute reference?

Comment: Unfortunately this is data from a chemistry analytical instrument. the data is not always the same length so I am forced to use a dynamic range. To clarify: the series I create does not seem to have an issue. There however seems to be an issue with more series being created that I never instructed excel to create.

Comment: Well it still seems to me that the UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2 might be the culprit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear data out of the chart before you add the data you want. At the beginning of your With/End With block, insert this:

```
With c
    Do Until c.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        c.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
```